# How can I make an executable JAR file in Eclipse of an Applet?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, executable-jar

I have been working on a small applet/game over the past week and someone recommended that I make it into a JAR file. After looking into this more on Google I found a tutorial and started to follow it. However, I soon realized that I needed to choose a class file that had a main method in it. Applets do not use a main so I was wondering how I could still make it into a JAR file. Thanks!

Comment: if your game meant to run as desktop, then replace applets with JFrames and JPanels, if it's meant to be a web-based game, then start your game inside HTML page using applet tag. in case of applet tag, the main applet is the main class

Answer (score 1):

> Applets do not use a main so I was wondering how I could still make it into a JAR file.

Yes they sure can.  In fact to have a good chance of being launched at all, applets need to be digitally signed, which can only be done with classes in a Jar.

> ..However, I soon realized that I needed to choose a class file that had a main method in it

That sounds like a problem with your IDE (you don't yet know how to use it, as opposed to having it use you).

BTW:

- Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
- Better to convert the applet to a desktop app., add a `main(String[])` method (jar it and sign it) and launch it from a link on a web page using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).